# How can I enable developer mode or turn on USB debugging on my Nexus 7(2012) running with Ubuntu touch 13 (saucy)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I installed Ubuntu touch 13 on my Nexus 7 V1, i cannot upgrade to the latest version via system update, so I want to reflash the system, but I cannot use USB debugging due to there is no developer mode in this version, so I cannot turn it on? is there anyone know how to do this ? 
PS: My PC is windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

In settings,go to About tab. There, the bottom tab should be developer mode. Activate it by clicking slider and you should be fine